# import google-play-service dependency red cross

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-maps, google-play-services

I'm french and I would use "google-play-service" so I followed the procedure on the [official web site to google here](https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=19nQzvKP-CVLd7_VrpwnHfl-AE9fjbJySowONZZtNHzw) and [here](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html)

And I'm blocked at this step :

> To add the dependency to Google Play Services into your project
>   Project -> Properties -> Android -> Library, Add -> google-play-services_lib "

I explain: Normally the "dependency" must be a "green check" at left.

After to press the button "Apply" the "green check" is always green,
but when I leave the windows (whith press button "OK") and I return on this windows (mouse right>properties>Android) I didn't have a "green check" but I have now a "red cross" (shoot3) ... I don't understand why ?

Did you have the same problem ?

[screenshot 1](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xb5ds5so324lol4/shoot1.PNG), [screenshot 2](https://www.dropbox.com/s/b2cexn5zc8fluex/shoot2.PNG) and [screenshot 3](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gly02xee2ckqix7/shoot3.PNG)

Comment: With all this shooting i'm not surprised the red cross is involved

Comment: It's good I've copy and past the library on another hard drive, and I restart this step and I didn't have a "red cross" :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to copy the `google-play-services_lib` next to your project's directory and open it from there.

Also you don't have to use Google Api's anymore - you can use Android Api.

Comment: Thank you.I also had same error.But I resolved by using above answer.

Comment: +1 - Worked for me. Had forgotten to check the "Copy projects into workspace" on Eclipse's Import feature.

Comment: To me this sucks, because I'm using a library as a git submodule, which I would like to reference from where it is. If I make a copy and reference it from the workspace all of a sudden I'm having a relative path from where I am, which can o cannot be the same on another machine. As I usually switch machines I have to be "fixing" these issues all the time.

Comment: @Bilthon You can always copy the full project to your submodule and add it as a simple library project. Or you can use gradle for the build system where you can define the version you need to use.

Comment: The main reason for this is eclipse is not able to import google play library from other drive correctly. Here is the complete explaination of this issue.
http://pissedoff-techie.blogspot.in/2014/07/unable-to-add-google-play-services.html

Comment: Google play services project and my project were in same in drive(Drive D),  but i couldn't fix the red cross problem and can not add play services project as library. But after i copied the play services project in main drive (Drive C),and then imported in workspace in drive D, the problem is strangely fixed.

Answer (score 2):

**I was also having same problem. Location of Google play services and your project should be same.**

If Google play services is in your work space then move your project to work space too.

**Move Project to work space:** Import project and check copy to work space!

Answer (score 0):

There can be one of the following mistakes:
1. Wrong Path
2. Since you have imported the project, so if by mistake you have deleted this imported project from workspace and while deleting you tick on delete contents from disk, it removes all files from android-sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib.In this cases re install google services from sdk manager.
3.while importing project dont forget to check the box saying "Copy projects into the workspace"