# gms.map absence of "Circle" and "CircleOptions" in package

Tags: android, maps, google-api

I would like to known why I don't have a class "Circle" and "CircleOptions"  within package of Adnroid google-play services,

because there is this class in the documentation :

http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Circle.html

[image: screenshot]

I do not think it is due to my "minSdkVersion" (which fixed at 14)

I you are any ideas for my problem ?

Thank you in advance,

Comment: what is the current version of google play service you are using?

Comment: my google play service is "Rev. n° 5"

Comment: within my android SDK Manager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem,

When I've installed google-play-services I follows the instructions for install but I'd some problems...

[import google-play-service dependency red cross](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14728293/import-google-play-service-dependency-red-cross)

because "Android" is installed in my Disk 'C' so there are a restriction access... due to the red cross for my previous problem...

I do not know why, but on the google-play-services copied before there are no 'Circle' and 'CircleOption'

so I just re-copied my "new" google-play-service out of my Disk 'C'(Windows) and It's work :-)

I've found the missing classes :D !