# The import com.google.android.gms cannot be resolved

Tags: android, google-maps, import

I am new to Android development. By following [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html%22this%20tutorial%22) I got errors `The import com.google.android.gms cannot be resolved` when I wrote the code into the `MainActivity.java`:

```
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
```

By searching for various fixes I made sure to try these out:

- I have downloaded Google API's for a particular API level through
  Android SDK manager.
- I checked off Google API as project build target.
- I have added `<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />`
  line into the `AndroidManifest.xml` as a child of `<application>` tag.
- I cleaned the project by selecting `Project->Clean...` and built it
  from scratch.
- I included `.jar` file for maps by right-clicking on my project, went
  to build path and added external archive locating it in my SDK: `android-sdk-windows\add-ons\addon_google_apis_google_inc_8\libs\maps`

Unfortunately, none of the above have helped.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

> I checked off Google API as project build target.

That is irrelevant, as that is for Maps V1, and you are trying to use Maps V2.

> I included .jar file for maps by right-clicking on my project, went to build path and added external archive locating it in my SDK: android-sdk-windows\add-ons\addon_google_apis_google_inc_8\libs\maps

This is doubly wrong.

First, **never manually modify the build path in an Android project**. If you are doing that, at best, you will crash at runtime, because the JAR you think you put in your project (via the manual build path change) is not in your APK. For an ordinary third-party JAR, put it in the `libs/` directory of your project, which will add it to your build path automatically *and* add its contents to your APK file.

However, Maps V2 is not a JAR. It is an Android library project that contains a JAR. You need the whole library project.

You need to import the `android-sdk-windows\add-ons\addon_google_apis_google_inc_8` project into Eclipse, then add it to your app [as a reference to an Android library project](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html#ReferencingLibraryProject).

Comment: You were right. I imported `google-play-services-lib` (which also contains the maps) then added it as a reference and those errors are now gone. Still I am not sure what to do about the `.jar` file already imported.  Should I be concerned about deleting it somehow?

Comment: @ArnoldasBendoraitis: Undo the manual change you made to your build path.

Comment: Clarification: Import the project into Eclipse using File → Import → Android → Existing Android Code into Workspace. And, of course, the directory you're looking for won't be called 'android-sdk-windows' if you're not using Windows. ;-)

Comment: @CommonsWare, Somehow if I add the Jar directly it works, but when I try to reference the project instead, it doesn't work. The reference shows the green tick when I do "Add". However, when I click "OK" and reopen Project > Properties, it turns to a red cross again. Do you know why this may be happening?

Comment: Maybe it's an update. But currently the path to import is
<sdk>\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib

Answer (score 55):

Another way is to let Eclipse do the import work for you. Hover your mouse over the `com.google.android.gms` import that can not be resolved and towards the bottom of the popup menu, select the **Fix project setup...** option as below. Then it'll prompt to import the google play services library. Select that and you should be good to go.

[image]

Comment: When I try this proposed solution, I receive this message: "No proposals have been found to fix the unresolvable reference to 'com.google.android.gms.internal.fn'. Click here to manually configure the build path or project 'CouponClub'." I already imported "google-play-services_lib" successfully, so I thought that would be enough to have access to com.google.android.gms.internal.fn.

Answer (score 19):

From my experience (Eclipse):

1. Added google-play-services_lib as a project and referenced it from my app.
2. Removed all jars added manually
3. Added google-play-services.jar in the "libs" folder of my project.
4. I had some big issues because I messed up with the Order and Export
   tab, so the working solution is (in this order): src, gen, Google APIs, Android Dependencies, Android Private Libraries (only this one checked to be exported).

Comment: Why add the Play Services jar manually, if Gradle will take care of it for you in the build?

Comment: Because I didn't have time to convert my projects into Android Studio format using Gradle. This is a solution for Eclipse IDE.

Answer (score 15):

In my case or all using android studio

you can import google play service

place in your `build.gradle`

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'
```

or latest version of play services depend in time you watch this answer

> More Specific import

please review this individual gradle imports

https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

**Google Maps**

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:7.8.0
```

> error may occurred

if you face error while you sync project with gradle files

[image]

make sure you install latest update

1- Android Support Repository.

2- Android Support Library.

3- Google Repository.

4-Google Play Services.

[image]

***You may need restart your android studio to response***

Answer (score 7):

Note that once you have imported the google-play-services_lib project into your IDE, you will also need to add google-play-services.jar to:
Project=>Properties=>Java build path=>Libraries=>Add JARs

Comment: The most simple one line answer. I was not able to figure out what is happening even after importing Play Services. Then I tired changing it to Google_apis. Finally, a single line solution worked for me.

Comment: Careful, this will cause problems:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15894143/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-com-google-android-gms-rstyleable-in-android

Answer (score 1):

Above solutions should solve your problem. If these do not, make sure you update your Android sdk using SDK manager and install the latest lib project and then repeat the above steps again.

Answer (score 1):

once again Make sure these 2 things happen correctly nothing more than that.
(FOR ECLIPSE USERS)

1) copy the jar file from --> C:\Users(your-username)\android-sdks\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib\libs\ **google-play-services.jar**

2) Right Click Project--> Build Path -> Add External Archive-> **google-play-services.jar**

Answer (score 1):

In Android Studio goto:
File -> Project Structure... -> Notifications (last entry) -> check Google Cloud Messaging

Wait a few seconds and you're done :)
import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService should be resolved properly

Answer (score 1):

In my case just add the below code to the build.gradle(:app)

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

I too had the same issue. Got it resolved by compiling with the latest sdk tool versions.(Play services,build tools etc). Sample build.gradle is shown below for reference.

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.abc.bcd"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that you are using ECLIPSE:

Right click PROJECT
PROPERTIES
ANDROID

If you have a version of ANDROID checked, you must change it to a GOOGLE API.
Choose a version of GOOGLE APIS compatible with your project's target version.

Comment: Please explain in details.

Comment: @DmitryIsakov what step would like me to clarify?

Comment: Looks like i did it... It was not an easy task to move from Eclipse to AStudio

Comment: @DmitryIsakov - i tried and had to stop because i couldnt afford to take the time off from development and dedicate it to migration.  could you please tell me some of the basic steps you took?

Answer (score -1):

In my case only after I added `gcm.jar` to lib folder, it started to work.
It was here: `C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\extras\google\gcm\gcm-client\dist`

So the `google-play-services.jar` didn't work...

Comment: This question is not about Google Map v1. It's about Google Map v2. gcm.jar is useless in this case.

Answer (score -3):

I had the same problem so that the dumb API I decided as follows
changing the import line

```
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
```