# How to import android-sdk-windows\add-ons\addon_google_apis_google_inc_8 into Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I am trying to run the Android ActivityRecognition sample app in Eclipse.

There are various imports that are not recognized such as:

import com.google.android.gms.location.DetectedActivity;

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15990075/the-import-com-google-android-gms-cannot-be-resolved) includes a probable answer.

But, I cannot figure out how to " import the android-sdk-windows\add-ons\addon_google_apis_google_inc_8 project into Eclipse".

If I try to import a project all I get is the MapDemos project.

I have tried **Import -> General -> Existing Projects into Workspace** and **Import -> Android -> Existing Android Code into Workspace**, but the only choice for projects to import the MapsDemo when I navigate to the addon_google_apis_google_inc_8 directory.

Thanks.

Comment: or else try to copy paste the same code as usually with same names  class...

Comment: What about 'new project/create protect from existing code', or something like that

Comment: Turns out it I needed to add the google-play-services_lib as described at [this page](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html#Setup).