# Google cast , what jar file are these located in?

Tags: java, android, google-cast

I am attempting to build and run an android google cast example. I can't seem to figure out which  jar these import are located in.

```
import com.google.android.gms.cast.ApplicationMetadata;
import com.google.android.gms.cast.Cast;
import com.google.android.gms.cast.Cast.ApplicationConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.cast.CastDevice;
import com.google.android.gms.cast.CastMediaControlIntent;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback;
```

Comment: This would help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15990075/the-import-com-google-android-gms-cannot-be-resolved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

these are part of Google Play Services library, you should download the latest one with the Android SDK Manager in ADT Tools

edit: they will be available in revision 15

Comment: I download the google play services library and added the google-play-services.jar to my build path , problem still persists and I don't see any other jars within that folder. Also I downloaded it using the android sdk manager.

Comment: @Fabii "These APIs are currently not available for development. They require Google Play services 4.2, which began rolling out to devices worldwide on February 3rd. Once the update to devices is complete, the corresponding Google Play services library (revision 15) will be available for you to begin using these APIs." https://developers.google.com/cast/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/cast/package-summary

Answer (score 2):

Google Play Services, revision 15 is available now.

[image]