# Error in setting up google play services

Tags: android, google-play-services

I am trying to setup Google play services using their [android-sample](https://github.com/playgameservices/android-samples/blob/master/README.md) project.
I had successfully imported **BaseGameUtils** and also the **google_play_services_lib** . After that i imported the sample project **Collect all the stars** (and added the **BaseGameUtils** to its build target) to test it.
But It is giving me error *( -- cannot be resolved)* on following two imports

```
import com.google.android.gms.appstate.AppStateClient;
import com.google.android.gms.appstate.OnStateLoadedListener;
```

I even try to import other example projects but they all are showing same error.
Below is a snapshot of error.
[image]

Comment: check link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15990075/the-import-com-google-android-gms-cannot-be-resolved

Answer (score 0):

just restart the eclipse and it will build the work space. This helped to solve the issue.

Comment: I did that many times but that doesn't helped. Errors are just on two mentioned imports all other goolgle-play-services related imported are fine ,which means that these two specific classes are missing from imported project

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is with google Play services library project it is not updated

Remove Library From your Project after that open the sdk manager and downloads any update for Google Play Services

then import the google play services library project from the following path

```
..../sdk/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib
```

to your workspace and build and add this project as a library project to your application project

after clean your application and build and run it should work.....