# The import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesAvailabilityException cannot be resolved

Tags: java, android

All other imports are OK.

Only

```
com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesAvailabilityException;
```

cannot be resolved.

I have imported google services lib and made my project reference it.

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15990075/the-import-com-google-android-gms-cannot-be-resolved) out.  Also, if you google *java android google import cannot be resolved*, you'll find a lot of results that may help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add googleplayservices lib that is inside your SDK.  Go to:

1. extras
2. google

Here you will find Google Play Services library.  If not then add it.  Install it just like you install versions of Android in ADT (Android Developer Tools).

Answer (score 0):

They have changed it to

> GooglePlayServicesRepairableException

```
 @Nullable
public static AdvertisingIdClient.Info getAdvertisingIdInfo(Context var0) throws IOException, IllegalStateException, GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException, GooglePlayServicesRepairableException {
```

Scroll this and check.

> GooglePlayServicesAvailabilityException was available in play-services-auth
>   . But Not Anymore