# The import com.google.android.gms.ads cannot be resolved

Tags: android, eclipse, google-play-services

I am getting error when i want to import google-play-service in Eclipse.
i have import google-play-service-project-lib in Eclipse
i have read all possible Q&A but nothing is work.
I have it added as Library and JAR manually
Then I have tried to clean my project ...

[image: Screenshot]

Is there anybody who can solve this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can use this way. First of all close projects which are using google-play-services library. Whenever your mouse over the com.google.android.gms import that can not be resolved and towards the bottom of the popup menu, select the "`Fix project setup`" option as below. Then it'll prompt to import the google-play-services library.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, try to download latest version of Google Play Services, then:

- Remove the existing library to add again manually,
- Go to your java build path,
- Under project tab add your library and then,
- Under order & export tab tick your library,
- Apply settings.

After all, just clean the project and library, it should work.

By the way, you can also check [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15990075/the-import-com-google-android-gms-cannot-be-resolved)

Comment: but i have latest version (check screenshot from Android SDK manager), and i read all pages about it. But is any other way how to update Google Play Services except by Download manager in Eclipse?

Comment: here are the 3 ways you can do it in official Android developer page: https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html

Answer (score 0):

To me it was just a matter of updating the dependencies.

```
dependencies {   
   implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:20.6.0'
}
```

I concluded that if it's already on the latest version, refresh the Gradle may solve the issue - or, as already recommended by Umit Kaya, remove the existing library and add it back.