# Error in Google Map XML in Android Studio

Tags: android, xml, google-maps, android-studio

I am relatively new in Android Studio so I tried to work with Google Map in here. I used my previous code which I wrote and compiled in Eclipse. However, Android Studio is still showing a syntax error:

```
cannot resolve symbol android
cannot resolve symbol gms
cannot resolve symbol maps 
cannot resolve symbol SupportMapFragment
```

I checked two different blog including googles developer guide. There were two options, I checked with both MapFragment and SupportMapFragment. The result is same for both cases.

The XML code is given below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:id="@+id/map"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" >This is error line.
/>
```

I dont have anything else in this XML file. 
Thank you.

Comment: at least mention what is the red sign told you !!

Comment: @MuhammedRefaat,  sorry. I forgot to mention. Just did.

Answer (score 0):

according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15990127/1638739), you have to import the project `android-sdk-windows\add-ons\addon_google_apis_google_inc_8` into your android-studio ([look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588064/how-do-i-add-a-library-project-to-the-android-studio) , [or here)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TForBjArUNg), then add it to your app([look here](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html#ReferencingLibraryProject)).