# Cant Import com.google.android.gms.actions.ReserveIntents

Tags: android

I want use ReserveIntents and try import *com.google.android.gms.actions.ReserveIntents*  but I have error

**The import com.google.android.gms cannot be 
     resolved**

I work in Eclipse.

Help

Comment: Google recently split up the play services into pieces, you may need to specifically include the gms library jar.

Comment: where I can get this library?

Comment: check out this to see if it'll answer your question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15990075/the-import-com-google-android-gms-cannot-be-resolved

Answer (score 0):

follow in below link steps 
http://hmkcode.com/adding-google-play-services-library-to-your-android-app/

and google-play-services.jar add in your project lib folder its will work