# Getting error in my android project. Android Version 19,

Tags: android, mapfragment

This is the LogCat:

```
08-04 01:21:52.616: D/AndroidRuntime(6835): Shutting down VM
08-04 01:21:52.631: E/AndroidRuntime(6835): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-04 01:21:52.631: E/AndroidRuntime(6835): Process: com.vape.main, PID: 6835
08-04 01:21:52.631: E/AndroidRuntime(6835): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #184: Error inflating class fragment
08-04 01:21:52.631: E/AndroidRuntime(6835):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:770)
08-04 01:21:52.631: E/AndroidRuntime(6835):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813)
08-04 01:21:52.631: E/AndroidRuntime(6835):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:821)
08-04 01:21:52.631: E/AndroidRuntime(6835):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:821)
08-04 01:21:52.631: E/AndroidRuntime(6835):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511)
08-04 01:21:52.631: E/AndroidRuntime(6835):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415)
08-04 01:21:52.631: E/AndroidRuntime(6835):     at com.vape.shops.ShopsFragment.onCreateView(ShopsFragment.java:137)
08-04 01:21:52.631: E/AndroidRuntime(6835):     at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2114)
08-04 01:21:52.631: E/AndroidRuntime(6835):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:904)
08-04 01:21:52.631: E/AndroidRuntime(6835):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1082)
08-04 01:21:52.631: E/AndroidRuntime(6835):     at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:833)
08-04 01:21:52.631: E/AndroidRuntime(6835):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
08-04 01:21:52.631: E/AndroidRuntime(6835):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:452)
08-04 01:21:52.631: E/AndroidRuntime(6835):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
08-04 01:21:52.631: E/AndroidRuntime(6835):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
08-04 01:21:52.631: E/AndroidRuntime(6835):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
08-04 01:21:52.631: E/AndroidRuntime(6835):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942)
08-04 01:21:52.631: E/AndroidRuntime(6835):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
08-04 01:21:52.631: E/AndroidRuntime(6835):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
08-04 01:21:52.631: E/AndroidRuntime(6835):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1388)
08-04 01:21:52.631: E/AndroidRuntime(6835):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1183)
08-04 01:21:52.631: E/AndroidRuntime(6835): Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
08-04 01:21:52.631: E/AndroidRuntime(6835):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:632)
08-04 01:21:52.631: E/AndroidRuntime(6835):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:596)
08-04 01:21:52.631: E/AndroidRuntime(6835):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2123)
08-04 01:21:52.631: E/AndroidRuntime(6835):     at android.view.LayoutInflater$FactoryMerger.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:178)
08-04 01:21:52.631: E/AndroidRuntime(6835):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:740)
08-04 01:21:52.631: E/AndroidRuntime(6835):     ... 20 more
08-04 01:21:52.631: E/AndroidRuntime(6835): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.vape.main-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
08-04 01:21:52.631: E/AndroidRuntime(6835):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
08-04 01:21:52.631: E/AndroidRuntime(6835):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
08-04 01:21:52.631: E/AndroidRuntime(6835):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
08-04 01:21:52.631: E/AndroidRuntime(6835):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:618)
08-04 01:21:52.631: E/AndroidRuntime(6835):     ... 24 more
08-04 01:21:52.631: E/AndroidRuntime(6835):     Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment
08-04 01:21:52.631: E/AndroidRuntime(6835):         at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
08-04 01:21:52.631: E/AndroidRuntime(6835):         at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
08-04 01:21:52.631: E/AndroidRuntime(6835):         at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
08-04 01:21:52.631: E/AndroidRuntime(6835):         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
08-04 01:21:52.631: E/AndroidRuntime(6835):         ... 26 more
08-04 01:21:52.631: E/AndroidRuntime(6835):     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

Comment: please reformat your question

Comment: can you give full description about that.

Comment: Which is the **code** behind this **error**?

Answer (score 0):

First, pls confirm that you can access `com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment`. Then delete the `bin` directory(in Eclipse) or `build/intermediates`(in AS). Hope this helps you.

Comment: How do i know if the project has access to  com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment ?

Comment: @user2681448 search for [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15990075/the-import-com-google-android-gms-cannot-be-resolved)

Answer (score 0):

Using an older google play service fixed the issue.