# import com.google.android.gms.maps cannot be resolved

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps, google-play-services

I have ./sdk/extras/google/google_play_services_froyo/libproject/google-play-se\
rvices_lib/libs/google-play-services.jar

In project -> Properties -> Android
Google APIs is selecteed.

I've tried to follow instructions from
[import cannot be resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15557380/import-cannot-be-resolved)

when I try Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Projects or
       Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path ->
I do not get the selction of google play jar.
When I try to import -> Android -> Existing Android Code into Workspace
 Eclipse does not recognise .jar files.

What am I missing?
Please, help.

Gene.

Comment: You do not need `Google APIs` to be selected, they are useless now and also you need more than just the jar file, you need to import the whole google play services library into your working space. You posted a link that contains all the answers to your questions so just follow that

Comment: The steps in the linked question are for windows and do not work for the ubuntu/eclipse setup. What are the exact steps to import google-play-services into the Workspace? I have ADT 23.02, eclipse platform 4.2.2

Comment: So substitute all the windows stuff with Linux stuff its still the same. You save the sdk somewhere and thats where it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that **oracle/sun** JDK works a lot better than the openJDK that comes with Ubuntu. Once I removed openJDK and installed oracle JDK1.8 all the menus worked a lot better.